# how to prevent events from launching using selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I use a selenium `IWebDriver`:

With this driver, I navigate through the pages to complete different actions:

```
driver.FindElement(path).Click();
```

I'm interested to block events that happen when clicking buttons.

Right now I'm modifying the `href` properties of the HTML page through code.

However I feel like this method is too tedious for what I'm doing.

Would there be a way to simply block the event using `selenium IWebDriver`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change any attribute of the element at runtime by using `ExecuteScript()` as below :-

```
IWebElement link = driver.FindElement(By..);

IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

link = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('href','your value');arguments[0].setAttribute('onclick',' '); return arguments[0]",link);

//now after modification you can click with your event
link.Click();
```

So in this you can modify or block any event attribute of element at runtime.

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: much lighter than my previous solution!! thanks a lot!!